# Downgrade PHP 5.4 to 5.3 in Debian

Tags: php, php5, debian

I had to do a Debian dist-upgrade on my server... in the process, PHP got upgraded to 5.4.  We use ioncube which only supports up to 5.3 atm, and I'm having some trouble finding how to downgrade to 5.3 from 5.4.  Anyone know how?

Comment: I certainly hope this doesn't mean you're using debian unstable (sid) on a server. Because that'd be a really, really, really bad idea.

Comment: I had to do a dist-upgrade to meet certain requirements for PCI compliance

Comment: Sid is named after the evil kid in Toy Story. He breaks toys. And servers.

Comment: If the packages.debian.com site is up-to-date (which I would believe that it is) then you must be on Debian Unstable. A dist-upgrade would not move you to a different release.

Comment: @duskwuff it's called unstable but it's not really unstable. In some occasions it may be better than the stable release. Obviously on a public server is not often the best solution, because it doesn't get fast security updates by the debian security team...

Comment: @dAm2K The whole point of sid/unstable is that it's where new packages go for testing. While it's *usually* not broken, there are no guarantees, and upgrading at the wrong moment *might* give you a broken system if you're unlucky. See http://www.debian.org/releases/sid/ for details.

Comment: I got it... it was simpler than I was making it. I had a sid reference in my sources list for some reason and that's what got php 5.4.  I removed that and added the wheezy sources and upgraded.  That fixed it.

Comment: "I had to do a dist-upgrade to meet certain requirements for PCI compliance"... and using an unstable distribution is good for PCI compliance?

Comment: @dAm2K: unstable does get speedy security updates these days, except for a short time (a month or so?) after a new release is promoted to stable so that isn't so much why you shouldn't use it in production. Updates go in there with relatively little testing compared to the other branches of course (as it exists in order to do some of that testing before updates are sent up the chain) which is why it isn't recommended for production use.

Answer (score 11):

Neither of the solutions above worked for me. What did work was pinning the necessary packages to the old stable such as

Add the following to `/etc/apt/sources.lst`

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
```

Create

`/etc/apt/preferences.d/preferences`

And add the packages you need downgraded such as in my case

```
Package: php5*
Pin: release a=oldstable
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: libapache2-mod-php5    
Pin: release a=oldstable
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: libapache2-mod-php5
Pin: release a=oldstable
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: php-pear
Pin: release a=oldstable
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 600
```

Then run the commands

```
aptitude update
aptitude reinstall <necessary packages>
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If you want to know which packages you need to upgrade just run :

```
dpkg -l|grep php|grep 5.4|awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/source/Sources: 404  Not Found [IP: 2610:148:1f10:3::89 80]

Comment: You need to update the sources.list file with this now: `deb http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free`

See https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSqueeze

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, but do it at your own risk. I didn't try it myself. ;)

- `apt-get remove php5`
- Download the [PHP5 package from Stable](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/all/php5/download)
- `dpkg --force php5_5.3.3-7+squeeze8_all.deb`
- `dpkg --set-selections PHP5 hold`

The last line to prevent upgrading to 5.4. When you're ready for 5.4, run `dpkg --set-selections PHP5 install`

IonCube for 5.4 is a little while out from what I've read.

Comment: I've got this `dpkg: error: unknown force/refuse option 'php5_5.3.3-7+squeeze13_all.deb'`

Comment: If you're still working on this, you should know that IonCube has been upgraded to work with PHP 5.4. Just stick with PHP 5.4 and download the latest IonCube libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can install both php versions parallel e.g. PHP 5.5x and 5.3x or even three PHP versions parallel e.g. PHP 5.5x , 5.4x and 5.3x using fastcgi.

**1. Install Libs, fastCGI, git**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libjpeg-dev libpng12-dev libmysqlclient-dev

sudo apt-get install git
cd /opt
sudo git clone https://github.com/cweiske/phpfarm

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi apache2-mpm-worker apache2-suexec
sudo a2enmod actions fastcgi suexec
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**2. Compile PHP and verify it**

```
cd /opt/phpfarm/src
sudo ./compile.sh 5.3.29
cd /opt/phpfarm/inst/bin
./php-5.3.29 --version
```

**3. Configure FastCGI**

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/cgi-bin
cd /var/www/cgi-bin
sudo nano php-cgi-5.3.29

#!/bin/sh
PHPRC="/etc/php5/cgi/5.3.29/"
export PHPRC
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
exec /opt/phpfarm/inst/bin/php-cgi-5.3.29
```

Make this file executable.

**4. Create a new virtual host**

Put this into your host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName fastcgidemo.dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/fastcgidemo

    #php-cgi setup
    #used for multiple php versions
    FastCgiServer /var/www/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.3.29
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin-php/ /var/www/cgi-bin/

    <Directory "/var/www/fastcgidemo">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

            AddHandler php-cgi .php
            Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.3.29
            <FilesMatch "\.php$">
                SetHandler php-cgi
            </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_fastcgidemo.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_fastcgidemo.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Add the domains to /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 fastcgidemo.dev
```

**5. Test everything**

Enable site and restart apache and create a new file with phpinfo() in /var/www/fastcgidemo to test your configuration.

Go to browser and type in fastcgidemo.dev

**Hope it helps!**

Full Tutorial on:

http://www.jabommi.de/wiki/downgrade-php-5-5-to-5-3-ubuntu-14-with-multiple-php-versions/

Answer (score 0):

#### Downgrading PHP 5.4 to 5.3

First check which versions are supported for php5:

```
apt-cache showpkg php5
```

Here is the script which you could find it useful (**it removes PHP 5.4 and install PHP 5.3**):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge `dpkg -l | grep php | grep -w 5.4 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs`
VERSION="php5_5.3.3-7+squeeze8_all" # CHANGES THIS WITH YOUR VERSION OF PACKAGE
sudo apt-get install php5=$VERSION php5-cli=$VERSION php5-common=$VERSION libapache2-mod-php5=$VERSION
sudo apt-get install php5=$VERSION php5-cli=$VERSION php5-common=$VERSION libapache2-mod-php5=$VERSION
sudo apt-get install php-pear=$VERSION php5-curl=$VERSION php5-gd=$VERSION php5-intl=$VERSION php5-mysql=$VERSION php5-pspell=$VERSION php5-recode=$VERSION php5-snmp=$VERSION php5-sqlite=$VERSION php5-tidy=$VERSION php5-xmlrpc=$VERSION php5-xsl=$VERSION
```

Where the available versions you can check by command: `apt-cache showpkg php5`

After the installation, verify it by command: `php --version`

Please be careful and don't install any other packages without package version specified (like php5-xcache), otherwise apt-get will replace your PHP instance with 5.4 again!

To prevent this happening, you can hold these packages.

#### Holding packages using dpkg

To hold packages by dpkg, you can execute the following command:

```
echo "php5 hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

To hold all PHP packages, run the following command:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep ^php5 | sed s/install/hold/g | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

The following command will show you holding status of your php packages:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep ^php
```

#### Holding packages using aptitude

You can also hold packages using aptitude e.g.:

```
sudo aptitude hold php5
```

Unhold:

```
sudo aptitude unhold php5
```

#### Extras

[See also the same questions for Ubuntu, for some more ideas.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116254/how-to-downgrade-from-php-5-4-to-5-3)

Answer (score 0):

I would first look at what I have installed

```
dpkg -l |grep php
```

then uninstall any php that is version 5.4 example ...

```
apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5 php-db php-pear php5 php5-cli php5-common
```

then you need to clean up the old files (not necessary but could help)

```
apt-get clean
```

then like above edit and pin

```
nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/preferences
```

if that still does not work repeat this but this time disable the repositories that are say wheeze and leave only the sid ones. 
you could

```
apt-get install --reinstall
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to do a full upgrade to wheezy by changing my apt sources to the wheezy sources.  Uninstalled php, upgraded the system with the new apt sources, installed php... everything's golden.

Comment: which sources you could at least post them. my apt sources doesn't have any php5.3 in there =/

Comment: Not an answer at all...